# Quadrangle vs. Quadrilateral

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, nouns, synonyms

Which of two words standing for geometric figure with four edges and angles is more common for english-speaking people?

P.S. I will use short word "quad" until I get answer for the question :)

Comment: "Quadrangle" tends to only be used for physical spaces, such as a square open area in the middle of a building.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrangle_(architecture)  For geometry, use "quadrilateral" to describe any four-sided shape.

Comment: @MaxWilliams: I thought the same until just now when somebody in a discussion on SO or maths.SE just used "quadrangle" in a technical geometry sense, which is what brought me here (-:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though luck, according to Ngram the two have nearly similar use. (See below.)

But as [quadrangle](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/quadrangle) is also used as synonym for Square, court, courtyard, plaza, enclosure, precinct, piazza...therefore a portion of its usage is for something else than what you're asking for.

Whereas [quadrilateral](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/quadrilateral) is **exclusively** used for the geometric figure, so the answer to your question is:

> **quadrilateral** is more common in the narrow definition you gave

[image]

Comment: Ngram shows you the usage of a particular word in the books, based on the number, it was used in those books.. not that they have "nearly similar use".

Answer (score 0):

Quadrangle is a geometric shape that has four angles. And logically, if any shape has four angles, then it will have four sides. Then it comes a quadrilateral.

I guess, you can use them interchangeably.

However, quadrangle is a word often used for an open space where people gather, say on a school or university campus.